# Adding values to an array that is local to a function without modifying the function itself

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function animal(){
  var species = new Array('Monkey', 'Dog', 'Cat');
  for(i=0;i<species.length;i++)
  {
    document.writeln(species[i]);
  }
}
```

How can I add another value to the `species` array without modifying the `animal()` function?

Comment: "without change the script within the function"... that's not going to be possible. Why can you not change the function?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to add values to the array without changing the code of this function for the simple reason that the `species` variable used there is a local variable declared within the scope of the function. So this variable is not visible to outside code. In addition to that the values of this array are hardcoded. So forget about it. Impossible without touching at the function implementation.

Comment: There's another way to change it?

Comment: Yes, of course. If you change the implementation of this function you could add whatever values you want to the array. The array could also be passed as argument. This way the caller of the function could provide his own array of values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your concerns, but javascript unlike some other languages can entirely overwrite a function.

So, assuming the above code, I could do:

```
window.animal = function(){
  var species = new Array('Monkey', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse', 'Fish');
  for(i=0;i<species.length;i++)
  {
    document.writeln(species[i]);
  }
}
```

That said, I would avoid the use of `document.writeln()`, I consider that function worse than `eval()`...
Also, as Darin hinted, I would also not define data local to a function if at all possible.

Comment: Why do you consider writeln worse than eval?

Comment: You can get around bad code written in `eval()`, but not so much with `writeln()`. I had a particular case in Joomla where it used `writeln()` to write html to the document. My template got the script through AJAX and when it got executed, I kept getting a blank page with the written HTML (since `writeln()` clears the page when called after the document loads).